# Aggregation and Sorting in Elastic Search

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to sort the Aggregated results of my query in elastic search

Equivalent SQL query:-  select col1, col2, sum(col3) from table group by col1,col2 order by sum(col3) desc;

I tried with the below query, it returns the result but not in sorting order which i am expecting

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "col1",
      "col2",
      "SUM"
    ],
    "excludes": []
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "col1",
    "col2"
  ],
  "aggregations": {
    "col1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "col1",
        "size": 200,
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error": false
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "col2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "col2",
            "size": 10,
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error": false
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "SUM_0": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "col3"
              }
            },
          "col3_bucket_sort": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              { "SUM_0": { "order": "desc" } } 
            ],
            "size": 3                                
          }
        }

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sampled Index data

```
{
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "products",
            "_id": "OJfBSXUB0GzAt2o_zVdS",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "product_name": "car",
                "product_type": "retail",
                "qty": 5
            }
        }
        {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "report",
            "_id": "OpfBSXUB0GzAt2o_zVfG1",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "product_name": "bike",
                "product_type": "retail",
                "qty": 5
            }
        },

       {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "report",
            "_id": "OpfBSXUB0GzAt2o_zVfG",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "product_name": "car",
                "product_type": "retail",
                "qty": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "report",
            "_id": "OpfBSXUB0GzAt2o_zVfG2",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "product_name": "bike",
                "product_type": "retail",
                "qty": 1
            }
        }
```

expected output :- Want to aggregate(group by) my documents on the basis of fields product_name and product_type and sorted by sum(qty)

Equivalent SQl Query:- select product_name, product_type, sum(qty) from product_table group by product_name, product_type order by sum(qty) desc;

```
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 2,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "product_name": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "car",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "product_type": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": retail,
                                "doc_count": 2,
                                "SUM_0": {
                                    "value":8
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                                {
                    "key": "bike",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "product_type": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": retail,
                                "doc_count": 2,
                                "SUM_0": {
                                    "value": 6
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

but i am getting below output i.e aggreating the docs successfully but sorting is not working on sum(qty)

```
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 2,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "product_name": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "bike",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "product_type": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": retail,
                                "doc_count": 2,
                                "SUM_0": {
                                    "value": 6
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "car",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "product_type": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": retail,
                                "doc_count": 2,
                                "SUM_0": {
                                    "value":8
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide some sample index data and your expected search result?

Comment: @Bhavya I have added the required info

Comment: it's been a long time. It would be great if you can upvote and accept my answer if my answer helped you resolve your issue 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are grouping your data by col1,col2 (i.e using two terms aggregation), therefore when you are trying to sort the result on the basis of sum aggregation using bucket sort aggregation the results are not coming appropriate.

You need to use [max bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-max-bucket-aggregation.html) that is a sibling pipeline aggregation which identifies the bucket(s) with the maximum value of a specified metric in a sibling aggregation and outputs both the value and the key(s) of the bucket(s).

And then you should perform [bucket sort aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html), on the aggregated result.

Adding a working example with index data(used same as that in the question), search query, and search result.

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "agg1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product_name.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "product_type.keyword"
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "SUM_0": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "qty"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "sum_max_bucket": {
          "max_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "agg2>SUM_0"        <-- note this
          }
        },
        "sum_bucket_sort": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": {
              "sum_max_bucket": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "agg1": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "car",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "agg2": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "retail",
                "doc_count": 2,
                "SUM_0": {
                  "value": 8.0          <-- note this
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sum_max_bucket": {
            "value": 8.0,
            "keys": [
              "retail"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "bike",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "agg2": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "retail",
                "doc_count": 2,
                "SUM_0": {
                  "value": 6.0       <-- note this
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sum_max_bucket": {
            "value": 6.0,
            "keys": [
              "retail"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: @Codinggeek it's been a long time. I hope you are doing well :) It would be great if you can upvote and accept my answer if my answer helped you resolve your issue 

Comment: @Codinggeek thank u for accepting the answer, can you please upvote the answer as well , by clicking the up arrow in front of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to an excerpt from [ES-Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation)

> The bucket_sort aggregation, like all pipeline aggregations, is
> executed after all other non-pipeline aggregations. This means the
> sorting only applies to whatever buckets are already returned from the
> parent aggregation. For example, if the parent aggregation is terms
> and its size is set to 10, the bucket_sort will only sort over those
> 10 returned term buckets.

Above is the reason why your query is not giving correct result.

Comment: I am also exploring how can we achieve what you want... I will update the answer.